# VSCode won't compile ANY of my C or Cpp files correctly, exe files refuse to close but aren't open

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, exe, raylib

When I run any files with VSCode, they compile into an exe file the first time, but I can't run them afterwards. When I try to delete the .exe file it doesn't work, saying the action cannot be completed because the file is open in another program. Originally I thought this was a problem with raylib exclusively, but after some testing, it's happening with all .exe files compiled from VSCode and Visual Studio 2022.

I can still run the .exe file fine, but any updates to the code past the first compile don't save.

There is nothing open in Task Manager or Process Explorer, My antivirus has been turned off, I have tried reinstalling VSC and VS2022, and there is seemingly nothing using the file. Why is it still saying something is using the .exe? Is it a problem with MinGW?

Comment: Any antivirus installed?

Comment: Yep, antivirus would be my first guess

Comment: My advice is to follow the [VSCode MinGW instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) and install MinGW via msys2. then use `pacman` to [install raylib](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-raylib?repo=ucrt64) instead of trying to build it from source. The command to install the ucrt x64 version of raylib is: `pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-raylib` from the msys2 terminal.